# Getting value from another table in PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I keep getting array to string conversion in this code.. please help me

```
 $qty_parse = oci_parse($conn, 'select qty from master_drawing');
 oci_execute($qty_parse);

 echo "<tr>\n";
 foreach ($row as $item) 
 {        
    //echo "  <td>".($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES):" ")."</td>\n";
    echo "  <td>".($item);
    if (is_numeric($item)){
        $quantity = oci_fetch_array($qty_parse, OCI_ASSOC);
          echo '/'.$quantity.'<meter value=10 min="2" max="10"></meter>';
     }else {
       echo ' ';
     }
 }
```

Comment: On what line ? The variable you try to echoing out must be an array.

Comment: Where and how `$row` is initialized? In which line error occurs?

Comment: Surprisingly, **...fetch_array** returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `oci_fetch_array()` returns array (array in function name should tell you something ;)). 
You can use `var_dump($quantity);` to see what was returned by this function.

I guess that what you need to do is something like this: `echo '/'.$quantity['qty'].'<meter value=10 min="2" max="10"></meter>';`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your $row variable is not defined. You can use next solution:

```
$qty_parse = oci_parse($conn, 'select qty from master_drawing');
    oci_execute($qty_parse);

while ($item = oci_fetch_array($qty_parse, OCI_ASSOC))
{
    echo "  <td>".($item['qty']);
    if (is_numeric($item['qty'])){
        echo '/'.$item['qty'].'<meter value=10 min="2" max="10"></meter>';
    }else {
        echo ' ';
    }
}
```

P.S. When oci getting associated array via OCI_ASSOC - your script gets $item variable like:

```
$item['qty'] = 'value';
```

If you want to get value from $item as string variable, redefine you variable on loop like:

```
$item = current($item);
```